# Autofill down only cells that have values

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel spreadsheet that has subtitles in the first column that groups similar items. I would like to autofill formulas down another column while not writing over the rows with the subtitles in the first column. I tried subgroups but that didn't help.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a filter by selecting the whole column > then Data tab > Filter,
2. Filter out Blank values:

[image]

3. Drag your formula down across the visible rows - it won't apply to hidden cells
4. Remove the filter when done to go back to normal.